# Use an array of Vector2f structs as an array of floats in-place

Tags: c#, struct

I have an array `Vector2f` structs that each contain two floats, and I want to pass it to a function that takes an array of floats. These structs represent 2d coordinates, and I want the end result to be `[x0, y0, x1, y1, ... xn, yn]`. Some code to demonstrate:

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class Test
{
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
    public struct Vector2f
    {
        float x;
        float y;

        public Vector2f(float x, float y)
        {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
        }
    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        Vector2f[] structs = new Vector2f[]
        {
            new Vector2f(1f, 2f),
            new Vector2f(3f, 4f)
        };

        // I want this to contain 1f, 2f, 3f, 4f
        // But Syntax error, cannot convert type!
        float[] floats = (float[])structs;
    }
}
```

This is easy by copying the contents into a new array of floats, but the data gets large and it would be nice not to duplicate it.

This may not be possible due to memory layout.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Question, is this supposed to be performant and avoid garbage-collection?  If No - LINQ can handle this nicely.  If this is part of a high-performance routine, more work/design is required.

Comment: The idea is to not copying the data, so yes, that element of performance is expected. I'm looking for help on if the "more work" is even possible. :)

Comment: This is not possible in managed without copying data. That's probably why none of the existing answers actually answers the question ("'**in-place**").

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't actually need to pass around a true array, but just something that can be accessed like an array, you can do something like this (untested):

```
public sealed class FloatArrayAdaptor : IReadOnlyList<float>
{
    private Vector2f[] _data;

    public FloatArrayAdaptor(Vector2f[] data)
    {
        _data = data;
    }

    public IEnumerator<float> GetEnumerator()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < _data.Length; i++)
        {
            yield return _data[i].x;
            yield return _data[i].y;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }

    public int Count
    {
        get { return 2*_data.Length; }
    }

    public float this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            //TODO: Add appropriate range checking and whatnot
            int i = index>>1;
            bool isX = (index & 0x1) == 0;
            return isX ? _data[i].x : _data[i].y;
        }
    }
}
```

You won't be able to 'recast' the type in C# like you can do in C.  The closest you can get is to use unsafe code and grab an actual float*, but even then you can't treat that pointer like a safe array for passing to methods that take an array.

---

I did some experimenting and it's possible with unsafe code to 'convert' the type, but it's a terrible, terrible hack and you shouldn't actually do this.  Nevertheless, it demonstrates some interesting things about the CLR object header data:

```
    public static unsafe void Main()
    {
        Vector2f[] data = new Vector2f[10];
        float[] dummy = new float[1];

        //NOTE: This is horrible and you should never actually do it
        //After this code, the original data array cannot be used safely anymore
        fixed (void* rawData = &data[0])
        fixed (void* rawDummy = &dummy[0])
        {
            int* intData = (int*)rawData;
            int* intDummy = (int*)rawDummy;

            //method table pointer is at X-4-sizeof(IntPtr)
            //This is what identifies the type via RTTI
            //We're going to forge our identity and change our size to change our type
            //This assumes x86
            intData[-2] = intDummy[-2];

            //Our length is doubled
            intData[-1] = 2*intData[-1];
        }

        if (data.GetType() == typeof(float[]))
            Console.WriteLine("Type is now float[]!");

        float[] floatData = (float[])(object)data;

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Basically we replace the method table pointer so that the type now appears to be a `float[]`, then we double the array's length field to compensate.  This compiles, runs and reports the type is now `float[]`.  That said, this might well blow up the GC later in some spectacular way and it's certainly quite implementation dependent, plus this doesn't deal with x64 vs. x86.  Still, interesting...  There's a reason this is called 'unsafe', though.  Hopefully this helps demonstrates why it can't be supported in a safe way, as the RTTI (via the method table pointer) is baked into the memory where the data is stored.

Comment: Interesting idea. A safe `float[]` is the requirement, but I could also use this solution in the reverse way so I could access a `float[]` as if it were a `Vector2f[]`. This would be something I might be able to use in the future, when I can refactor out all `Vector2f[]`. I'm going to keep the question requirements as they are for now, although this is a good answer for a fresh project!

Comment: @31eee384, see the edit for an example of why, even though this is technically, sort-of possible in C#, it's a really bad idea.  Better not try and use the original array after the change...

Comment: Wow, impressive work! However... seeing that you were able to do that in that amount of code (albeit unsafely and with terrifying side effects) actually gives me hope that something similar might have been implemented in the standard library. At this point I think someone would have pointed that function out if it existed, though, so I think I can accept this answer and hope that someone uses it in the future to write that method. :)

Comment: @31eee384, I don't think it would be implemented in the standard library, as it invalidates the object state for the original variable.  Anybody using that variable would assume that GetType() would still return `typeof(Vector2f[])`, but it no longer does.  There's no way to create two different 'views' of the same memory, because the RTTI (well, the method table pointer, where the table contains the RTTI) is stored directly in the same memory as the contents of the array (just at a negative offset from the first array element.)

Comment: Oh, I see! I wasn't separating the concepts properly in my head. So, basically, the array can't be treated as a different type of array because at the lowest level the indexing rules and type are stored in the object. Then, because there's no way to tell C# "I won't use this reference after I pass it to this function" it's impossible to do this sort of conversion. If that's correct (at least conceptually), I think this is certainly the correct answer!

Comment: One problem is that the `-2` offset is an implementation detail. And might (or might not) change in the future. Since this breaks type safety, as Dan pointed out this might also break memory management (and garbage collection) altogether. Give you +1 for the interesting experiment though ;)

Comment: @31eee384, That's basically correct.  Strictly speaking, the way you index the array is specified in the IL code that the compiler generates, not in the type information.  The main thing the hack does is convince the compiler that it's okay to cast the object to a float[] (and thus emit array access instructions for float elements) by lying about what kind of array it is, thus bypassing the type safety checking.  It breaks compiler-expected invariants, though (in particular, a prior cached reference to the 'old' method table could create... interesting bugs).

Answer (score 1):

One way to convert it would be to implement an enumeration:

```
IEnumerable<Single> GetFloats(IEnumerable<Vector2f> vectorList)
{
    foreach (var vect in vectorList)
    {
        yield return vect.x;
        yield return vect.y;
    }
}
```

But this still makes a lot of copies: one to the `var` and one for each value (when yielding).

Struct are value types, so you're bound to make copies anyway.

I understand that you would like to be able to just convert the same piece of memory into a new type. But unfortunately for your case, arrays in C# are not just a pointer to a piece of memory. There are also some metadata associated with it (like the `Length` of the array) and some special memory alignment. So I don't think it is possible to do otherwise.

**edit:** Even if you could do it (this is far from my expertise, but maybe with some IL code emiting it is possible), you may encounter problem with the way managed memory is handled: it can be moved a lot of times. It does not have a static location in memory. The garbage collector compact memory after each generation collection (not every time, but still).

This is an intersting question though. And I would like other experts to give us some of their light here ;)

**edit:**  A more efficient way to avoid some garbage collection, like it was suggested in the comments:

```
float[] GetFloats(Vector2f[] vectorArray)
{
    var floats = new float[vectorArray.Length*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < vectorArray.Length; ++i)
    {
        floats[i*2] = vectorArray[i].x;
        floats[i*2 + 1] = vectorArray[i].y;
    }

    return floats;
}
```

**edit:** Still not a direct answer to your question but a more efficient copy that use pointers, adapted from [Unsafe Code Tutorial](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/Library/aa288474.aspx) (note that this requires to compile with `/unsafe`):

```
static unsafe void FastCopy(Vector2f[] src, float[] dst, Int32 count)
{
    if (src == null || dst == null)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }

    int srcLen = src.Length;
    int dstLen = dst.Length;
    if (srcLen < count ||
        dstLen < count*2)
    {
        throw new ArgumentException();
    }
    // The following fixed statement pins the location of
    // the src and dst objects in memory so that they will
    // not be moved by garbage collection.          
    fixed (Vector2f* pSrc = src)
    {
        fixed (float* pDst = dst)
        {
            byte* ps = (byte*)pSrc;
            byte* pd = (byte*)pDst;
            count *= 8;

            // Loop over the count in blocks of 4 bytes, copying a
            // float (4 bytes) at a time:
            for (int n = 0; n < count/4; n++)
            {
                *((float*)pd) = *((float*)ps);
                pd += 4;
                ps += 4;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting approach, has a cleanliness to it I appreciate. It still produces a copy of the original, unfortunately.

Comment: Struct are value types, so you're bound to make copies anyway.

Comment: The hope is that I'm able to use the existing array as a different type of array, therefore not making any copies at all since the conversion is entirely in the reference type. This might be impossible, but I'd like to see some evidence before abandoning an in-place conversion.

Comment: RE: your edit, even with the metadata, if the structs are stored sequentially in memory, I'd expect it to be possible for another array to be constructed with different metadata that refers to those sequential floats as floats instead of as structs. I agree that it might not be as straightforward as C or something, but that's why I'm asking the question. :)

Comment: If the code is supposed to be performant and avoid garbage collection, one could insist on an `ICollection<T>` and avoid the GC of enumerators which have to be disposed.

Comment: I just remembered that arrays of structs [box](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664476%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) the structs, so I think you're probably right, although it's not really about the metadata. (*EDIT*): Wait, [maybe not?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/560184/in-c-are-the-values-in-a-liststruct-boxed)

Comment: Collection of value types were boxed in very earlier version of .Net. But it was quickly corrected (when generics were introduced).

Comment: Ah, that makes sense! Thanks for this answer, it's good for the performance aspect of the question. I still want to wait a few weeks to see if someone can 100% rule out the in-place conversion though.

Answer (score 1):

Now trying to answer why it is not possible.

C# is a type-safe language. This means that only certain conversion (cast) are allowed on compatible types. This explains why this code is not allowed:

```
Vector2f[] structs;
float[] floats = (float[])structs;
```

Indeed, C# use references instead of pointers. One of the difference is that a reference is not a static location in memory. Object can be moved during garbage collection.

However, C# allow some pointer arithmetic with `unsafe` code. To do so, the garbage collector must be notified that memory should not be moved (and that references must not be invalidated) for the considered objects. This is done with the `fixed` keyword.

In other word, to get a pointer to a reference object (same logic for a struct), you first need to freeze the object location in memory (this is also called pinned memory) :

```
fixed (Vector2f* pStructs = structs)
fixed (float* pFloats = floats)
{
    ...
```

Now that all is fixed you are not allowed to change the address of those pointers. This for example is not allowed:

```
pFloats = (float*)pStructs // this will change the address of pFloats which is fixed: illegal
```

Also you cannot convert a pointer back to a reference:

```
float[] floats = (float[])pFloats; // not allowed
```

In conclusion, once you get pointer you are able to move some bytes from one location to another, but you cannot change the location of the corresponding references (only the data can be moved).

Hope this answer your question.

**As a side note**, if you have a lot of performance-critical operations, you may consider implementing it in C++, expose some high-level functions and call some functions from C#.

Comment: This all makes sense and I think is useful to answering the question, but I still don't feel like it's outside the realm of possibility for .NET to have a "low-level" way to force this kind of cast in safe code resulting in the original reference to an array of `Vector2f` and a new reference to an array of `float`. Good explanation of the limits of the unsafe boundary, too--haven't played with that much. If nothing happens for a few days I'm satisfied to accept this answer as "can't do it."

Answer (score 0):

```
    Vector2f[] structs = new Vector2f[]
    {
        new Vector2f(1f, 2f),
        new Vector2f(3f, 4f)
    }
```

Maybe try this once.

And maybe you should try to take the 1f, 2f, 3f and 4f from the array and than it might been possible to put it into an array of floats.

Comment: Sorry, `new []` is just a syntactic sugar for `new Vector2f[]` because the compiler can figure out the type on its own. That's not where the problem lies. I'll edit the question to make this more clear.