# List of value type: Changes on member of object from list are not saved in list

Tags: c#, arrays, c++-cli, generic-list

CLocation is a C++CLI `value class` (would be a `struct` in C#) with public members `x`, `y`, `z`.

```
List<CLocation>^ listloc = gcnew List<CLocation>;
listloc->Add (CLocation (1,2,3));
listloc[0].x = 5;   // FAILS, '5' is not stored.

array<CLocation>^ aloc = gcnew array<CLocation>(1);
aloc[0] = CLocation (1,2,3);
aloc[0].x = 5;   // WORKS
```

Why is `5` not saved in the member of the object in the list, while it is perfectly saved in the member of the object of the array?

Does list access return a copy of the object as Marc Gravell wrote in [In C#, are the values in a List<struct> boxed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/560184/in-c-are-the-values-in-a-liststruct-boxed) ?

Comment: Yes - `listloc[0]` is an indexer access - it's returning a value. Compare that with `aloc[0]` which is a variable, not a value (at least in C# spec lingo... and it's going to do the same thing in C++, regardless of the actual terminology used). The C# compiler would give you an error at the third line, knowing that it's a pointless assignment.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Thanks!!! Unfortunately this info is not available in MSDN, where I expected it: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ebtbkkc(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Well it is, really... it's a property. (An indexer is just a property with a parameter.) A property access *has* to be classified as a value... it's returning something. *All* properties work that way. Think of it as a regular method call - if you'd written `listloc.GetItem(0).x = 5;` what would you expect to happen?

Comment: @JonSkeet  Dammit! I know properties work that way, but I really didn't notice that `Item` *is* a property...

Comment: The EDG parser catches it, at least in recent VS versions, the one that generates the IntelliSense data.  Produces the red squiggles and "expression must be a modifiable lvalue" in the Error List window.  Well, you perhaps found a good reason to update :)